# How to get the first and last digit a user entered in C#

Tags: c#

Completely new to programming and I am in need of some help with this assignment. We have to make a program where we ask the user to enter a number in inches and convert it into yards/feet/remainingInches, now I got this part down.

However the last part of the assignment tells us to display the first and last digit that the user entered. I am not sure how to go about this. I know I can get the last digit by taking that `value % 10`.

But I'm not sure about the first value. Some of my peers said to use `.Length()` but they are unsure as well since nothing has worked for them. Can someone please help me out?

Here is my code so far

```
  Console.WriteLine("Gimme a number in inches");
  int userInches = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  Console.WriteLine("we will now calculate these inches into yards and feet and remaining inches.");
  int inchesInFeet = 12;
  int inchesInYards = 36;
  int yards = userInches / inchesInYards;
  int remainingInches = userInches % inchesInYards;
  int feet = remainingInches / inchesInFeet;
  int inches = remainingInches % inchesInFeet;

  //display yards, feet and inches with respective lables
  Console.WriteLine(userInches + " inches is: ");
  Console.WriteLine(yards + " yards");
  Console.WriteLine(feet + " feet");
  Console.WriteLine(inches + " inches");

  Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You can convert the number to a string and then use Substring.

Comment: Or just read `var read = Console.ReadLine(); int userInches = Convert.ToInt32(read);` and then you get both.

Comment: Also I am not allowed to use loops or if statements

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people on here are a bit sensitive about helping with obvious homework problems. Half of the assignment is figuring it out.

Without trying to give too much, and still answering:

Try to treat it as a string. You can access a string like this:

```
var s = "this is a string";
Console.Write(s[0]); // t
Console.Write(s[1]); // h
Console.Write(s[2]); // i
...
```

Hopefully, you should be able to see what to do from here.

Comment: I can tell by the negative responses, but thank you so much. I think i know what to do from here

Comment: Hey, don't sweat it. We all had to start somewhere. In the future, you'll get more help if you show that you've done your "due diligence" with some failed attempts or research.

Comment: Yeah it's just that a lot of the ways to do it, the instructor isn't letting us or will count off for some reason. he wants us to do it a certain way without getting ahead. But you're right I can't ask for the answers all the time. Thanks again, your help worked out and I got my program to work.

Comment: No problem man. If you feel like its right, make sure to mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is a homework question where you show a part of your work, I appreciate that, even though some of the community may not see this as a nice question.

The last digit of any `number` is always `number % 10`, as you noticed. This is a good start.

Let's continue on this way you understand already : the `int` way (even though I prefer and recommend the `string` way given by @Adam Schiavone in the other answer)

You should know that: when you do **integer division**, the result is just truncated. This means:

`number / 10` will get rid of the last digit, if `number` is `int`. So if the number is 2 digits long, you will get the first digit !

```
int a = 45 / 10;   // value of 'a' is 4 !
int b = 234 / 10;  // value of 'b' is 23, not very interesting for you
```

`number / 100` will get the last two digits away, if `number` is an `int`. So if the number is 3 digits long, you will get the first digit !

```
int c = 45 / 100;   // value of 'c' is 0, not very interesting for you
int d = 234 / 100;  // value of 'd' is 2 !
int e = 7893 / 100; // value of 'e' is 78, not very interesting for you
```

If you notice `10` is like 10 to the power 1, `100` is like 10 to the power 2, and you notice the pattern making link between number length and power of 10 to divide the number with, you may understand the *general algorithm* to use to get the first digit of your number.

Comment: Thanks! And thank you for being so nice to a complete newbie. I was actually able to solve it by following @Adam Schiavone 's advice. This is what i did to solve it with some rearranging. 
 string stringEntered = Console.ReadLine();
            int userInches = Convert.ToInt32(stringEntered);

 Console.WriteLine("First character: {0} and Last character: {1}",
                stringEntered[0], stringEntered[stringEntered.Length - 1]);

            Console.ReadKey();

Comment: @snewz Yes, I saw that you accepted it and I also voted his answer up. His is the simplest C# way to do it, IMHO. But feel free to post your working code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get a lot of complementary recommendations, if you want to dig further.

Comment: I appreciate it man, thank you for elaborating even further than you needed because you helped me learn something much more with that integer division. I know i'll use it again and i'll be able to reference this! I cannot tell you how thankful I am for all the help! And I definitely will later on